# using jquery to select table columns greater than n?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in jquery to select all td columns greater than say 4?  I have a table with 16 columns and I initially only want the first 4 shown.

I know I can use:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(5)').hide();
```

to hide them one at a time of put a class on all of them but it would be nice if there was a simpler jquery way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $('tr').each(
        function(){
           $(this).find('td:gt(3)').hide();
        });
```

[Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7SDpr/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7SDpr/).

Comment: Only trouble with `.find()` is that it will affect nested tables (if any) as well. You'll bet better off using `.children()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:gt()` selector to do this:

```
$('tr td:gt(4)').hide();
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

EDIT:

As Patrick pointed out, this won't work for every row.  You'll need to use .each to apply this for each row.

```
$('tr').each(
    function() {
       $(this, ).find('td:gt(4)').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Remember, JavaScript uses zero-based arrays. Should be (`$('tr td:gt(3)')`).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in [an `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) [using `.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kEByC/

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).children().slice(3).hide();
});
```

or like this [using `.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kEByC/1

```
$('tr > td:nth-child(3)').nextAll().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('tr > td:nth-child(n+3)').hide();
```